# How does one make Evolution work with Exchange 2010?

Tags: exchange, evolution

Preferably natively (Exchange mode), so that my calendar, etc, all sync up properly.  It was working fine under our old version of Exchange (2007?), but broke with the upgrade to Exchange 2010.  Done the usual remove the account, re-add, etc.  Prefer not to drop down to IMAP mode for mail only.

Comment: Note:  I've also been unable to get IMAP to work between the latest Evolution and Exchange.  Evolution IMAP works fine against other servers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Linux

Yes, it should work.
You can install it by the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install evolution-ews
```

or less recommended way:

```
sudo apt-get install evolution-mapi
```

And then execute `evolution`.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Looks like it should work now as it has specific connectors for 2007+.  However, I'm unable to confirm as Evolution starts with a big white screen with 2 unmarked buttons and no text anywhere on my current system...  :-)

Comment: Execute evolution from the console and check for any errors which can point you to the problem.

Comment: Nothing that looks applicable to the problem.  Throws a series of errors about failing to create config files for my user, but nothing involving display/fonts, etc.

Comment: Heh.  Interestingly enough if I do X over SSH from another machine it works fine.  Throws all the same errors both ways, but just doesn't work locally.  Go figure.  :-)  Oh, and it talks to the server just fine now, guess it got an update at some point.

Comment: "Official" Gnome documentation [recommends](https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/exchange-connectors-overview.html.en) `evolution-ews` over `evolution-mapi`.

Answer (score 7):

Heres some more information that might be helpful,

[Connecting Evolution Mail Client to Exchange 2010](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000378.htm)

Pete

---

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (and I am battling with the very same issue), this doesn't work. After configuring the connector, and entering the password, a message pops up saying that the server runs version 5.5 of MS Exchange and the connector is not compatible. You don't get any further errors, and you can download the list of folders, but you can't open any of them. This is the state of play as I experience with Evolution 2.22.

Comment: Well, thanks for the confirmation.  I guess it's not just me.  :-(

Comment: exchange 2010 works perfectly for me with [MAPI](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000378.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar issue.

I have two computers at home and installed on both of them **Ubuntu 10.04**.  But in one (laptop) I just upgraded through the ***Update Manager*** from 9.10, while on the other (desktop) I did a full reinstall with a CD *(and forgot to backup the Evolution data)*.

Well, the results have been different on both, regarding Evolution.  In the laptop, I can still see and download emails from my job's Exchange Server.  While on the desktop, Evolution seems to connect and see the server, but nothing is downloaded.  I even removed the 
account a couple of times, to see if I had mis-configured it.

My next step is to backup the Evolution data and setup from the laptop and copy it to the desktop.  I will let you know the outcome.

Hopefully, this piece of information might help you.

### Update (5/26/2010)

Just tried it and worked!
I backed up my Exchange account from my laptop, and restored it into my desktop Evolution program.  Then I pressed "Send/Receive" and new emails where downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

[DavMail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/) Gateway 4.5.0 worked smoothly with Evolution 3.4.4 for accessing mail, calendar, and corporate directory on Exchange 2010 SP1 from Debian Wheezy.

It is fairly quick and easy to setup:

1. Download the Debian package from the developers on the DavMail website, for example v4.5.0:

   ```
   wget http://superb-dca3.dl.sourceforge.net/project/davmail/davmail/4.5.0/davmail_4.5.0-2292-1_all.deb
   ```
2. Install the package

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i davmail_4.5.0-2292-1_all.deb
   ```
3. Obtain URL of Exchange server (skip if you know it)

   The EWS plugin for Evolution can help [discover the URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332364.aspx):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install evolution-ews
   ```

   Start the 'Add a new account' wizard in Evolution. Fill in name and your Exchange email, choose 'Exchange Web Services' for server type, fill in your username and hit Fetch URL. Cancel the wizard.
4. Create ~/.davmail.properties

   ```
   davmail.server=true
   davmail.enableEws=auto

   # Paste the Exchange server URL discovered in previous step
   davmail.url=https://subdomain.corporatedomain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx

   # Choose ports above 1024 to be able to run as regular user
   davmail.imapPort=1993
   davmail.smtpPort=1465
   davmail.ldapPort=1636
   davmail.popPort=1995
   davmail.caldavPort=8443
   ```
5. Launch `davmail` in a terminal to see the output in case something goes wrong. For a permanent setup, see [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-davmail-exchange-gateway-on-a-debian-7-vps) for an init script.
6. In Evolution add an IMAP+ mail account

   ```
   Server: localhost
   Port: 1993
   Security: No encryption
   Auth Type: Password
   ```

   (It is safe to be unencrypted, this is a localhost connection between client and davmail only).
7. Add an address book:

   ```
   General tab:
    Type: On LDAP Servers
    Server: localhost
    Port: 1636
    Security: No encryption
    Login method: Using distinguished name (DN)
    Login: <your.corporate.windows.domain>\<username>

   Details tab:
    Search base: ou=people
    Search scope: Sub
   ```
8. Add a calendar:

   ```
   Type: CalDAV
   URL: caldav://localhost:8443
   Username: <your.corporate.windows.domain>\<username>
   User email: <your exchage email>
   Browse server for a Calendar -- you should find you calendar there
   ```

References:

- [How To Setup a DavMail Exchange Gateway on a Debian 7 VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-davmail-exchange-gateway-on-a-debian-7-vps)
- [Use Thunderbird/Evolution with Microsoft Exchange 2007/2010](http://www.linux-answered.com/2012/06/12/use-thunderbird-evolution-with-microsoft-exchange-2007-2010/)
- [Microsoft Exchange 2007/2010 calendar/address book with Evolution](https://www.linux-answered.com/2012/06/21/use-microsoft-exchange-2007-2010-calendar-address-book-evolution/)

Answer (score 0):

When my Company mail server upgraded from *Microsoft Windows Exchange Server **2003*** to *Microsoft Windows Exchange Server **2007*** my Evolution mail client stopped receiving mail (in Ubuntu).

I got the network administrator to allow access to the server via IMAP. Evolution had no problem connecting via IMAP.

Answer (score 0):

you also need to add python-samba in Ubuntu 13.04

> sudo apt-get install python-samba

Obviously, for those using debian based apt-get. Given that Kenorb's answer was accepted by Brian one is led to assume that apt is the package manager.

Comment: Well, perhaps it's required, but no... First off, my distro doesn't use apt...  Secondly, yast auto resolves dependencies so there's no need to go manually installing extra libraries.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch This comment for future reference of anyone encountering this question only:  Apt also auto-resolves dependencies, but there was a bug whereby Ubuntu's evolution-ews wasn't marked as having a dependency on python-samba but did have such a dependency in actuality.  I believe it's now been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Evolution Preferences

Note: In Account editor change the option Encryption Method "Security", select the option "SSL on dedicated port".